# How to do task scheduling in PHP Code Igniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, cron

I am developing android application in which I am using push notifications using app server developed in php, It is working fine, But I want to schedule notifications to send to devices, I am new to PHP and don't know how to schedule some event using PHP. While searching for this problem I got to know that it can be done using cron jobs, but I am not understanding how to do it.
Please help me.

Comment: In the best case you should set cron jobs to request that URL every hour using wget or CURL in the *NIX command line:

0 1 * * * wget http://www.mywebsite.com/controller/function

As this URL is accessible publicly secure it with a parameter like http://www.mywebsite.com/controller/function?key=my_secret_key_here

Also take a look at this online service: http://cronless.com/

Answer (score 0):

I would add to @rawatHemant that you can force a Controller's method to be invoked via console:

```
public function index()
{
    if($this->input->is_cli_request() == false)
    {
        echo "This script only runs from command line." . PHP_EOL;
        exit();
    }
}
```

Comment: How it will implement.?